# Filtering over Infinite List

Tags: haskell

From `ghci`, I tried to `filter` on numbers less than or equal to 7:

```
ghci> filter (<= 7) [1..]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7Interrupted.
```

But I had to cancel out of it (see **Interrupted**) since the program did not seem to terminate (at least that's what I understand it to mean).

Why does the program hang in this code?

Comment: Because `(<= 7)` is not a condition to _end_ the filtering, but to throw out elements. There might be another element that is `<= 7` at the 10 millionth position (as far as `filter` knows).

Comment: If you have a situation like this, you should be using `takeWhile` instead.

Comment: Basically, GHC is not smart enough to prove that the sequence ends after the 7th element. In this case, Haskell's `filter` cannot "reach inside" the function to determine that it is `\x -> x <= 7` (can stop after 7) and not, say `\x -> x <= 7 || x == 1000000` (can stop after 1 million). It does not *analyze* the function you pass it, but rather it simply *calls* it until it can find an output to yield.

Comment: @ChrisDrost: Strictly speaking, it's not that it's not "smart enough," but rather that *it just doesn't work that way*. The definition of `filter` requires that filtering a non-finite list *must* produce a non-finite list as well; if `filter` returned `[]` on a list that doesn't have `[]` after a finite number of conses, it would be a violation of its equations.

Comment: @LuisCasillas It's both. There is a direct implication from "no function can work the way that you want" to "therefore, *this* function doesn't work the way that you want" -- but I agree that it's really valuable also to see *how* the function doesn't work the way that he wants, which indeed requires analyzing the equations.